Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read null property (reading 'value')
I have JavaScript codes that give this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read null property (reading 'value')

Here are my codes
1.
let imgBox = document.getElementById("imgBox");
let qrImage = document.getElementById("qrImage");
let qrText = document.getElementById("qrText");

function generateQR() {
  if (qrText.value.length > 0) {
    qrImage.src =
      "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=250x250&data=" +
      qrText.value;

    imgBox.classList.add("show-img");
  } else {
    qrText.classList.add("error");
    setTimeout(() => {
      rText.classList.remove("error");
    });
  }
}




document.getElementById("qrButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
  let qrInput = document.getElementById("qrText").value;

  new QRCode(document.getElementById(qrImage), qrInput);
});

What does this error mean?
I expected it to generate QR Code, but it returns the above error.

Does it really say "null property", or is it actually "property of null"? The error means that qrText == null, which means that there's no element with id="qrText" when you run the code.

Welcome to SO! Please share your HTML to have a [mre].
